# how embed origin site address in a link in html?

Tags: html, referrer

Assume there is a link like `<a href="mysite.com">click here</a>` in a footer of a website.
is there any way to change this link somehow that the admin of mysite.com website could detect from which site this user is coming from?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply adding some parameters, like `mysite.com?whoIam=itsMe`. Obviously the admin of the destination site will have to check a log of requests or he need to create some code for that particular parameter and to keep track of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```html
<a href="https://example.com" 
onclick="this.href = 'https://example.com/?ref='+encodeURIComponent(location.host)">click here</a>
```